# .Net Core Identity AuthenticationCookie not working

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, cookies, identity

I recently ran into a problem with my net5.0 application (upgraded from net core 3.1). I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity to sign in and it works perfectly fine. After deploying it to the production machine the login is still working and I receive my cookie. But after calling the url on the next day I am not logged in despite having my auth cookie (it's valid for 30 days). On my local machine hosted on IIS it works fine. Here are parts of my code:

Startup.cs:
ConfigureServices

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logoff");
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyApplication";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

I am using the ProtectPersonalData attribute to encrypt userdata in the database with a keyring:

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
    {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        config.Stores.ProtectPersonalData = true;
        config.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Configure

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

And this is the cookie in Firefox:
[cookie][1]

In my understanding this cookie should be send to the server on every request for that domain. And even though Firefox states, that it was accessed last on the exact time of my request it has no effect.
If you need any further code let me know. Any help is appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTSuR.png

Comment: Do you set the token expire time?

Comment: I am using "options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);" for my ApplicationCookie as seen above. My PasswordSignInAsync does not contain any logic for expire time

Comment: It is a cookie expire time, you need to configure the token expire time.

Comment: I don't think I get what you're saying. Aren't the tokens just for email confirmation, pw reset etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like everything was ok with my code. The error was within the IIS Configuration. As I am using DataProtection the ApplicationPool should have "load userprofile" set to true, because otherwise it can not store the keyring and data is lost after application shutdown/restart. After changing that on the production server it seems to be working now.